# How to convert object into string

Tags: javascript, html, object, dom, getelementbyid

So I was using getElementById method and consoled it when I'm consoling with string it just displays string object like this `[Object]` i want to display it as Object

```
var element = document.getElementById('input');
console.log("the view element "+ element );
```

Comment: `console.log("the view element ", element );` - use comma

Comment: Oh yeah (y) thanks man

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
console.log ('text', element)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

console.log(element);

//Now you can explode the object

Comment: As in you really want the `the view element ` text to be included? I don't know if you can do that on the same line.  Break it into two lines?

Answer (score 0):

console.**dir** is your friend.

```js
var el = document.querySelector('div');
console.dir(el);
```

```html
<div>Stuff</div>
```